# Script in function won't echo

Tags: php, echo

When I try to echo

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function rotate_$num(number) {
    num = number%$i;
    $('.$num').fadeOut('normal');
    $('#'+(num+1)).fadeIn('normal');
    number++;
    setTimeout('rotate_$num('+number+')',300);
}
</script>
```

from inside a function in PHP it doesn't echo out, but when I change `<script>` to `<div>` it works. Also, it works when the echo is just in a php file with nothing else but the echo in it, it works.

Here's the entire function:

```
function rename_name($name) {
    return str_replace(' ', '', $name);
}
function pane($result) {
    if($result['title']) {$title = ': '.$result['title'];}
    $name = rename_name($result[name]);
        echo "<div class='pane $name'>
            <h2>$result[name]$title</h2>";
        if (is_array($result['data'])) {
            $num = rand(0, 9999);
            foreach($result['data'] as $option) {

        $i++;

        if($i == 1) $display = 'block'; else $display = 'none';
                echo "<div id='$num$i' class='$num' style='display: $display;'><h3>$option[data]<span       class='whats'>$option[kind]</span></h3></div>";

            }
            //The below will echo when script is changed to div, why should it matter?
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> function rotate_$num(number) { num = number%$i;

                    $('.$num').fadeOut('normal');
                    $('#'+(num+1)).fadeIn('normal');

                    number++;

                    setTimeout('rotate_$num('+number+')',300);
                }
            </script>";
            //The above will echo when script is changed to div, why should it matter?
        }
        else {
            echo "<h3>".$result['data']."<span class='whats'>$result[kind]</span></h3>";
        }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

And here is the $result array being passed to it

```
Array
(
    [name] => Mint
    [type] => 0
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 67
                    [kind] => hits today
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 24
                    [kind] => unique hits today
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 158351
                    [kind] => hits total
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 17826
                    [kind] => unique hits total
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Hey man, it's FRIDAY. Do NOT ask hard question on Fridays. People wanna have fun! jk

Comment: Could it be a browser plugin/antivirus preventing javascript from writing `<script>` tags?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the source of your problem, but are you declaring an initial $i outside the part of the code you showed us?

Comment: The code is really a mess here. Please do yourself and favor and use a template engine.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're declaring a new Javascript function for every result, instead of passing $num and $i to an existing function outside the loop?

Comment: @SpyrosP That's not very good advice. PHP itself is a templating engine. Do you really want to add more overhead with another engine on top of it?

Comment: @NullUserException: PHP itself is a horrible template engine. Especially if non-programmers will be editing the "templates". http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engines-in-php is a nice article to read.

Comment: Seriously though PHP XTemplate is a **great** one.

Comment: @NullUserException : There are template engines(you can even write one in a single class) that add virtually no overhead. I don't care to add a tiny overhead(i don't talk about smarty which is slow) to make my code humane.

Comment: @Zyber by `doesn't echo out` do you mean you can't find it in the DOM or that it's not visible on the page?

Comment: @SpyrosP you are leaving out the fact that parsed templates can be cached eliminating any overhead in the first place.  PHPTAL respect!

Comment: @tandu, with caching or not ( i tend to not really like it ), would never prefer to write worse code in order to save tiny overhead, unless it was critical.

Comment: @SpyrosP I agree with you 100%.  Templates are great for organization and separation of view and logic.  However, NullUserException's argument was that PHP is already a good templating engine and the overhead is not worth it, but I was still pointing out that you can use templates to generate less overhead anyway.

Comment: @NullUserException: PHP is a templating engine, but it's not being used as one here :/

Comment: @tandu : I'm actually using PHP for my template system based on that http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/beyond-template-engine. Still, the idea is using a template engine, even if it does not have internal parsing and can actually not even be considered an engine by itself.

Comment: Ack..so much for xml compliance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put in the exact same array, and got the expected output.

Are you fetching this data via AJAX then placing it on the page? Javascript cannot write script tags to the DOM (at least, not via `innerHTML`) and will therefore simply ignore them.

If this AJAX data, it looks like you're using lots of unnecessary bandwidth to make this transfer, especially by transferring what is essentially the same script over and over. I'd recommend transferring just the data (either in HTML or, if you're feeling really cool, in JSON then having the client run the template), then letting the original script handle the rotation. Not only will it actually *work*, but it'll also come out cleaner and more manageable. After all, if I were working on this app and wanted to change how pane rotation works, this is not where I'd look first for that particular snippet of code.

Comment: The workflow is ajax->every separate pane finder->look if pane has username/password/install->find those if they exist->pane data fetcher->format pane data->return to ajax->write on page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I try not to let strings span multiple lines like you've done with your echo statement. Try using heredoc notation, like this.

```
   $javascript = <<EOT
<script type='text/javascript'> function rotate_$num(number) { num = number%$i;
    $('.$num').fadeOut('normal');
    $('#'+(num+1)).fadeIn('normal');
    number++;
    setTimeout('rotate_$num('+number+')',300);
}
</script>
EOT;
    echo $javascript;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc